# NetBeans exe files

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, netbeans

I downloaded `netbeans-8.1-linux.sh`. After installation there are many `.exe` files in the installation folder such as `netbeans.exe`, `netbeans64.exe`, `app.exe`, `app64.exe`, `nbexec.exe`, `pre7_app.exe` and etc. Why are they there?

**EDIT:** I installed NetBeans by Ubuntu Software and it hasn't even got JavaFX plug-ins! It also installs `openjdk 1.8.0_9` and replace it with already installed `oracle jdk1.8.0_92`!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04...

Answer (score 4):

NetBeans 8.1 is in the default repositories of Ubuntu 16.04. To install it, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install netbeans
```

You can also install NetBeans 8.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 from the Software application. Then there isn't .exe files cruft, just the netbeans package.The version of NetBeans in the Ubuntu 16.04 default repositories is NetBeans 8 which targets Java 8 as its compatible Java version.

Comment: AFAIK that one in the repositories isn't the full version of NetBeans. It just installs Java plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bewildering bundle of download options available on the [Netbeans download page](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) and you have obviously picked up some Windows installation files along the way.

Can I suggest that *for Trusty Tahr* at least rather than download and install in this manner you use this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vajdics/netbeans-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netbeans-installer
```

This will install everything neatly...